# What is the layout setting for SKETCH with Foundation 6

Tags: css, sketchapp

I am designing for Foundation 6 using SKETCH app. What is the layout setting for this framework. I know for bootstrap its:

```
Total width: 1170px
Num. of Col.: 12 (Gutter outside)
Gutter width: 3px
Col. Width: 95px
```

Whats the setting for foundation? any difference?

Answer (score 1):

As of this moment, these are the [settings](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/blob/41fb72d7da4359cd3659fe21867423e2fc1f9547/scss/settings/_settings.scss#L116) in Foundation:

```
// 3. The Grid
// -----------

$grid-row-width: $global-width;
$grid-column-count: 12;
$grid-column-gutter: (
  small: 20px,
  medium: 30px,
);
$grid-column-align-edge: true;
$grid-column-alias: 'columns';
$block-grid-max: 8;
```

Earlier in the file, you'll see that `$global-width` is `rem-calc(1200)` (basically `1200px`).

So I have this basically setup in the Sketch layout settings for a larger desktop design:

Total width: 1200px
Offset: 0px, then click the "Center" button
Number of Columns: 12
Gutter Width: 30px
Column Width: 72px